# ¿Por qué no funciona esta funcion en jquery?

Tags: jquery

Tiene que comprobar que las dos contraseñas introducidas sean iguales pero no lo hace... Al introducir la primera letra se añade la clase valid en vez de invalid...

```
var iguales = false;
 $('input[type=password]').keyup(function() {
   if ($('#regpass').val == $('#regrepass').val){
                $('#nonequal').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
                iguales = true;
            } else {
                $('#nonequal').addClass('invalid').removeClass('valid');
                iguales = false;
            }
   }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Al parecer estás accediendo la propiedad `val` y no el método `val()` del objeto:

```
if ($('#regpass').val() == $('#regrepass').val()){
```

http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: Más apropiadamente, está comparando la función consigo misma en vez de comparar los resultados de llamar a la función.